# Read files into R faster than while{rbind(read.table)}

Tags: r, while-loop, rbind, read.table

I'm reading a number of daily Apache logfiles into R. The files are all named "logfile_" plus their date, e.g. `logfile_2019-12-30`. Here is how I read the files:

```
path <- "/path/to/logs/"

beginning <- as.Date("2019-12-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")
ending <- as.Date("2019-12-31", format="%Y-%m-%d")

d <- beginning
dat <- data.frame()
while (d < ending)
{
    dat <- rbind(dat, read.table(paste0(path, "logfile_", d), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
    d <- d + 1                    
}
```

For one month (with about a million lines of log entries) the `while`-loop takes about four minutes to execute. I'd like to read and process files from several years but don't want to wait hours.

**How can I read in the files more efficiently and faster?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table::rbindlist` should be faster along with `fread`

```
library(data.table)
beginning <- as.Date("2019-12-01")
ending <- as.Date("2019-12-31")

out <- rbindlist(lapply(paste0(path, "logfile_", 
                 seq(beginning, ending, by = "1 day")), fread))
```

Or you can also use `dplyr::bind_rows`

```
out <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(paste0(path, "logfile_", 
      seq(beginning, ending, by = "1 day")), read.table, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Comment: If you are going to bring `data.table` into it (and that is a Good Thing) then try using `fread` for ultra-fast CSV file input.

Comment: `data.table()` seems to find reading Apache logfiles difficult. Your first example returns an error: `Error in rbindlist(...): Item 58 has 3 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 12 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE. In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Found and resolved improper quoting out-of-sample. First healed line 2419: ...` I know it's from characters in the requested URL or the referer. `read.table()` handles these fine.

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis Maybe `fread` needs some additional arguments. You can use the second option or use `out <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(paste0(path, "logfile_", 
      seq(beginning, ending, by = "1 day")), read.table, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))` with `read.table`

Comment: Your second example, using dplyr, takes 11 seconds for my sample. That's nice. Thank you.

Comment: With that amendment (from your last comment) your first example takes 9 seconds, using my sample. I cannot upvote due to low rep, but I'll accept this answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @Spacedman Trying different existing commands to read in my Apache logfiles, I found that only `read.table` does not need any manual fiddling (see the error quoted in my comment above). So while `fread` may be faster than `read.table`, it does not handle Apache logfiles as well. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using sequence function to create a vector of dates then use this vector inside the read.table as follows;

```
path <- "/path/to/logs/"

beginning <- as.Date("2019-12-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")
ending <- as.Date("2019-12-31", format="%Y-%m-%d")

file_names <- paste0(path, "logfile_", seq(beginning, ending ,by = 1))
do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, read.table, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Comment: `lapply(file_names, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` is missing some vital parts.

Comment: Do you mean function parameters that are missing? Generally it depends on the format of the file in the question only stringsAsFactors is missing. I also added sep these are generally the main ones but in general it depends on the file.

Comment: You'e got `lapply` with the file names and the `stringsAsFactors` but no function to apply to the list. Did you mean `lapply(file_names, read.table, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`? The code as written can't possibly work.

Comment: Using my sample, your solution finishes in 16 seconds, which is a huge improvement. Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot upvote because of low rep.